# Kong plugin store value in Kubernetes secret

Tags: kubernetes, kong, external-secrets-operator

I have this KongPlugin on Kubernetes

```
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
config: 
  remove:
    headers:
    - Authorization
  append:
    headers:
    - Authorization:Basic <SECRET>
plugin: request-transformer
```

Is it possible to move the header Authorization to a Kubernetes secret?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using the **request-transformer** Enterprise version you can do it.

> config.append.headers optional
>
> Type: array of string elements     List of headername:value pairs. If the
> header is not set, set it with the given value. If it is already set,
> a new header with the same name and the new value will be set.

> This field is referenceable, which means it can be securely stored as
> a secret in a vault. References must follow a specific format.

Ref : https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/request-transformer-advanced/

There is no direct way as much i have tried if not exterprise version, but you can update or write the plugin code and create the docker image and run it.

Here is example code which append the headers : https://github.com/Kong/kong-plugin-request-transformer/blob/master/kong/plugins/request-transformer/access.lua#L228

You can read article do build custom docker image with plugin code : https://faun.pub/building-kong-custom-docker-image-add-a-customized-kong-plugin-2157a381d7fd